# How to place a couple of textviews, icons above bottomsheet with recyclerview and move along with bottomsheet?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, audio-streaming, bottom-sheet

Hi I am working in AOD (Audio On Demand)/Audio streaming platform in android. I am new to this platform. I  am struggling with a part of a design thing. I have searched a lot and ended with no answer. Below given is the design I have to work.

[image: player screen image]

As you can see in this design, there is an image background with gradient and there is a play lyrics button on top of it and below there is a couple of text views and icons and playback control options(pause, previous,next icons) below that there is an seek bar (redline) attached to bottom sheet and bottom sheet contains recyclerview. Bottom view is initially in top position not in bottom.

[image: player screen with lyrics]

As you can see in above image, If user clicks the play lyrics button, the bottomsheet is moved to bottom along with those textview and playback control options. And have to show lyrics above the textview. How to achieve this? I have searched a lot but I don't see anything like this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the easiest way of doing this is using `MotionLayout`.

With it, you can set start and end layouts, and simply start the animation between the two when user clicks on play button.

For more information on `MotionLayout`, visit [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout), where you can find extensive documentation, examples, and also additional links (including to a codelab) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you share me any examples here?